# Pyautogui Script and Looping

Tags: python, api, loops, automation, pyautogui

Made a script to copy info to an API.
How do i repeat this script to run a certain number of times?

Sorry, just started playing around with python for work so i'm not too sure of what i'm doing just yet.
Thank you!

```
import pyautogui as pag
import time
time.sleep (3)

pag.click(448, 98, interval = 0.25) #click NEW bookmark
pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab') #switch to spreadsheet; must be on the correct cell
pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'c', interval=0.25) #copies first name from spreadsheet
pag.press('tab') #move to last name cell before switch to API
pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab') #switch back to API
pag.scroll(50) #scrolls to view recruiter
pag.click(192, 297) #clicks first name box to have a place to press enter
pag.press('enter') #saves entered information
```

Comment: Had to shorten the code down to be able to post :)

Comment: What you need to learn is ['for loops'](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), namely `for _ in range(n):`. Your question is very general and has nothing to do with `pyautogui` per se. Possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440493/for-loops-novice

Answer (score 0):

This will run `n` times.

```
import pyautogui as pag
import time
time.sleep (3)

for i in range(n):
    pag.click(448, 98, interval = 0.25) #click NEW bookmark
    pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab') #switch to spreadsheet; must be on the correct cell
    pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'c', interval=0.25) #copies first name from spreadsheet
    pag.press('tab') #move to last name cell before switch to API
    pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab') #switch back to API
    pag.scroll(50) #scrolls to view recruiter
    pag.click(192, 297) #clicks first name box to have a place to press enter
    pag.press('enter') #saves entered information
```

Answer (score 0):

For just repeating this block of code *n* number of times without any change to the code in each iteration (repetition), I would suggest using a standard `for` loop as below:

```
for i in range(n):
    # Your block of code indented here
```

If you do not know what this is, I'd suggest you to go through some online resources that teach basics of programming in python.

PS: If you already have an understanding of how Python libraries and APIs work (if not then don't worry, you can learn these yourself in no time if you're motivated), I would suggest checking out certain libraries like `selenium` that allow you to control a browser through code (without hard coding where to click). Python's main advantage is the plethora of libraries that allow you to do virtually any task on your computer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on selenium. Looking through it right now!